# Keras module not found on mac

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, keras

I tried to install Keras using the command `$pip install keras` on my mac which is running macOS Sierra the latest version. And the terminal shows me all of this, which I don't understand wether it installed or not:

```
    Collecting keras
    Requirement already satisfied: six in/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python 
    (from keras)
    Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /Library/Python/2.7/site-
    packages (from keras)
    Collecting theano (from keras)
    Collecting numpy>=1.9.1 (from theano->keras)
    Using cached numpy-1.13.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
    Collecting scipy>=0.14 (from theano->keras)
    Using cached scipy-0.19.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
    Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy, theano, keras
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1

    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has 
    been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to 
    the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially 
    uninstall the project.

    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:

    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 
    342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, 
    in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 
    754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 
    115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
    File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
    OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 
    '/var/folders/tx/vqg_k_812hn8mn4wz2v6dy3r0000gn/T/pip-uaC1pi-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

and then when I run `>>> import keras` it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named keras
```

How can I fix this error and get Keras installed properly? Also, tensorflow installed just fine on my computer, but I don't know why this isn't.

Comment: The install threw an exception.  So it didn't install.  So when you try to import Keras, certainly it wouldn't work.  Try `sudo pip install keras`

Comment: I already tried that and it throws an exception again. And it doesn't work when I try to use `import keras`

Answer (score 0):

Did you use from tensorflow import keras  ?

Sometimes you might have to type this command from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential